# C# label string to int conversion error

Tags: c#

I am making a very small RPG game in C# to practice some skill (and to have fun!). I have gotten pretty far with the images, buttons and such.
My issue is that I am being thrown an error when trying to convert my label strings into integers to be compared for my `attackingPhase()` method.

Here is my code and a screenshot of the error.

I believe my code is correct but I can not figure out as to why the error is being thrown.

Thank you for all help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RPG
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Form1 mainForm = null;

    public Form2(Form callingForm)
    {
        mainForm = callingForm as Form1;
        InitializeComponent();

        pictureBox1.Image = mainForm.MyPictureBoxEnemy.Image;
        pictureBox2.Image = mainForm.MyPictureBoxHero.Image;
        lbl_Health_Value_Enemy.Text = "100";
        lbl_Health_Value_Hero.Text = "100";

    }

    public void attackingPhase()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();

        int enemy_damage = rnd.Next(1, 25);
        int hero_damage = rnd.Next(2, 15);

        var enemyHealth = Convert.ToInt32(lbl_Health_Value_Enemy);
        var heroHealth = Convert.ToInt32(lbl_Health_Value_Hero);

        if((enemyHealth & heroHealth) > 0)
        {
            enemyHealth = enemyHealth - enemy_damage;
            heroHealth = heroHealth - hero_damage;
        } else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("DEAD");
        }

        lbl_Health_Value_Enemy.Text = enemyHealth.ToString();
        lbl_Health_Value_Hero.Text = heroHealth.ToString();
    }

    private void btnAttack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        attackingPhase();
    }
}
}
```

---

[image: Error Message]

Comment: the error is telling you exactly what's wrong `lbl_Health_Value_Enemy` change to `lbl_Health_Value_Enemy.Text`

Comment: Agree with methodman, also I recommend  using Int32.TryParse(string, out yourint) to handle

Comment: The error does not say the issue is with the `.Text` I did try to do .toString but the error was not clear to me. Not sure why this would be downvoted when asking for help though. I asked a valid question

Comment: @Ashton this is something basic that you should know in regards to assigning a value to a Text Property vs using the Object name or type do some more basic reading / tutorials when you get a spare moment.. :)

Comment: you're comment has nothing to do with the obvious.. cheers..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert the Text property of a label,

```
var enemyHealth = Convert.ToInt32(lbl_Health_value_Enemy.Text);
var heroHealth = Convert.ToInt32(lbl_Health_Value_Hero.Text);
```

Comment: GAH! Of course! I tried it with `.toString()` and it also threw the error but of course it needs to be .Text because of the label. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: I will! I've been downvoted for some reason but to me it was a valid question and i provided all information :/ I will mark as answer when the time limit for doing so is up. Thank you!

Comment: @Ashton Upvoted it, probably because you have attached the screenshot rather than code

Comment: I did attach the code however. I gave the form where the code was at. The screenshot was only to show the error message. Thank you though!